# OrientDB short path is very slow

Tags: search, orientdb, shortest-path

I would like to find the shortest path between two nodes using OrientDB. I did implement it as follows:

```
    String   s = "select expand( ShortestPath(" + first_vertex.getId() +
    ", " + second_vertex.getId() + ", "+ direction +")  ) ";
```

to print only vertices

```
        for (Vertex v : (Iterable<Vertex>) call_shortest_path.g.command(
                new OCommandSQL(s)).execute()) {  
      System.out.println(v.getProperty("name").toString()); 
        }
```

It works, however very slow comparing to neo4j. Is there any way of improvement?

Comment: hi, which version are you using? thnx

Comment: Whats' the difference in time with Neo4j? Did you try with 2.2.0-rc1?

Comment: I am using Neo4j Version: 2.3.3 and OrientDB Version: 2.1.12. The time difference is really great (Neo4j: 50 Milliseconds and OrientDB is 170 Milliseconds). In retrieving relationships for a given nodes OrientDB is much faster but in searching short path is not the case.

Comment: I tried the 2.2.0-rc1 and actually no change in performance.

Answer (score 0):

try to modify the query this way:

```
String   s = "select shortestPath(" + first_vertex.getId() + ", " + second_vertex.getId() + ", "+ direction +") unwind shortestPath";
```

---

**EDIT**

this is working for me, though I'm not sure if it's faster than yours:

```
String s = "select expand (shortestPath) from (select shortestPath(" + first_vertex.getId() + ", " + second_vertex.getId() + ", " + direction + ") unwind shortestPath)";
```

Comment: it returns no result

Comment: thanks for your update. However, it is even slower (220 MS) than my first try (134 MS).